# ng-if and $index off by 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to display a schedule and I want to create a break after each group of matches within a week. For example, I want an `<hr>` after the first five matches in week 1. Then again after five matches of week 2. What I have now includes the first six matches, and then every five after that. Why? What do I need to do to break after every five?

Note: As an additional enhancement, it would be nice to break when the week changes, and not just assume there will be five matches each week. If someone has a way to solve that as well, that would be great.

As you can see below, the first six matches show, which incorrectly includes the first match of week two.

[image]

This is in my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="match in state.eastSchedule.Matches">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-center">{{match.WeekNumber}}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">{{match.AwayPlayer}}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">{{match.HomePlayer}}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">{{match.Score}}</div>
        </div>
        <hr ng-if="$index > 0 && $index % 5 == 0" style="border-color:black;" />
    </div>
```

I also tried removing the part about only using an index > 0, but then I get a break after the very first match, and then every five after that.

```
<hr ng-if="$index > 0 && $index % 5 == 0" style="border-color:black;" />
```

Comment: Maybe you just want to put that `<hr>` above the `<div class='row'>` ... b/c when the 6th iteration starts (when `$index` is 5) it will output the row div and then the hr.

Comment: That worked. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML is structured so that the `<div class="row">` appears before the `<hr>` tag.

So on the 6th iteration of the loop (second week, when `$index` is 5), it prints the `<div class="row">` for the first item in the second week then the `<hr>`.

To fix you can move the `<hr>` tag so that it is above `<div class="row">`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" >
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    
    <div ng-repeat="item in arr">
      {{item}}
      <hr ng-if="(($index+1) % 5) == 0">
    </div>
     
     
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$index start with 0. so in first case you are printing 6 values i.e. index 0 1 2 3 4 5. after that it will work fine like it will take next 5.

Comment: use ($index+1)%5 == 0